# How do I bind roboVm ios code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, binding, libgdx, robovm

How do I bind roboVM ios code?

This is ios code:

```
/* Designated initializer */

- (id)initWithClientID:(NSString *)clientID 
          clientSecret:(NSString *)clientSecret
           redirectURL:(NSString *)redirectURL
           accessToken:(NSString *)accessToken
          refreshToken:(NSString *)refreshToken;


+ (KAAuth *)sharedAuth;

- (void)registerWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionHandler;
- (void)registerNewAccountWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

IOS call source code:

```
[[KAAuth sharedAuth] registerNewAccountWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self afterLogin:error];
    });
}];
```